# Joining/Merging two QuerySets on two keys

Tags: python, django

i would like to merge two QuerySets on two keys.

```
class ModelA(models.Model)
  text = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class ModelB(models.Model)
  value = models.CharField(max_length=10)
  model_a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
  additionalkey =  models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

Suppose i already have a queryset on all ModelA-objects and I need corresponding entries from a second Model (ModelB) which has a ForeignKey-RelationShip to ModelA depending on an additional key. What would be the fastest and most efficient way to achieve this?

Doing this with a loop over all entries would hit the database for every entry in the ModelA-QuerySet.

My idea is to get all ModelB Objects at once and join/merge it with the complete ModelA-set where the ForeignKey and the additionalkey fit.

Any ideas or hints anyone?

Edit:

Ok, to be more precise. I *already have* a queryset of ModelA. After all I would like to have a queryset with informations from both tables in *one queryset* (or something else i can iterate over in a template).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but maybe:

ModelA.objects.all().filter(modelb__additionalkey='foo')

Answer (score 0):

You could use the list of pk's from you modelA queryset to filter modelB:

```
pk_list = model_a_queryset.values_list('pk', flat=True)
ModelB.objects.filter(model_a__pk__in=pk_list)
```

or you could just get the first queryset by filtering ModelB with some sort of value:

```
ModelB.objects.filter(model_a__title="foo")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
modela = ModelA.objects.filter()
modelb = ModelB.objects.filter()

......................    

{% for a in modela %}
    {{....}}

    {% for b in a.modelb %}
        {{....}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```